Transfer weights to selected area only
I am currently skinning character with face and I wanted to use plane as a proxy for mouth. My thought was to simply skin the plane with proper weights and then transfer the weights only to the mouth area on the meain mesh. However I cant find a way to do this in Blender. For reference in Maya this would work with simple Copy Skin Weights and selected vertices.

You can select the vertices of the destination mesh, assign them to a vertex group named "Limit Influence", then add a Data Transfer modifier, targeting the source mesh and using the limit vertex group.
Check Vertex Data and Vertex Groups options and press "Generate Data layers" Button, then Apply the modifier (Ctrl A).
You can choose the merging method with previous weights (Replace, add, multiply...) and the copying algorithm (Copy from nearest Vertex generally works well).


Thank you this works pretty well!
